# What should I do when a user promotes his answer on other answers' comments?

Tags: discussion

Although most times a user has legitimate reasons to link to his answer in another answer's comments on the same post, sometimes it seems to me that someone with nothing relevant "spams" other answers trying to attract attention to his own.

I have got some rough examples now, but generally it goes like:

The answerer here spams link to his answer in other answers' comments:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41313435

In these two I don't see the relevance of comments. They don't add anything more than just a shortcut to own answer in comments of the probably most visualized one:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4302942
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757256

IMO, the noise generated by comment would be better used with significant information or update/fix question with minor changes. Edit is too much underrated - *Why bother? Answers give more points?*

While I see nothing wrong with commenting something useful in answers, linking one's own answer as an alternative with other approach/solution/etc, sometimes it seems leaving this land heading to the border of the advertising land with answers with minor significant content.

Comment: Saying "look at my answer" isn't constructive. Users can already look at the answer, which can explain why it should be considered over others. Hijacking other answers for visibility isn't good. Flag them as too chatty. If the user is very persistent, raise a custom flag.

Comment: It may be good idea to include clearly wrong comments in the post... Two posts you linked to seem to have reasonable comments that promote other answers, probably bad once already gone.

Comment: One reason for linking to a new answer may be that the question was asked some years ago, is still valid, but the product/language has changed and there is a new answer — but the new answer is hidden a long way down the list of answers because it has not yet got the up-votes. An example of this conundrum is [`clock_gettime()` alternative in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x). Starting with the release of macOS Sierra, the long-missing `clock_gettime()` is available. There's an answer that says so, but it is a long way below the others.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This case is a valid reason indeed. IMO that's a "pseudo-subjective" issue: sometimes it's clearly legitime, sometimes it's clearly a self-promotion, and sometimes a grey area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the comment really adds very little that's relevant, it's noise, and should be flagged for deletion accordingly. We don't want anything unnecessary cluttering up the site.

In particular, unless the comment actually provides some additional information about the answer it's posted on, such as some indication of a potential flaw or limitation, it's junk. If it's nothing more than "here is another way to do this, please look at it", out it goes!